# ORMLite - JOIN query on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: android, ormlite

I have some store data that contains Sections and Items that are part of those sections, such as:

```
sections: [
{ section_uid: "onSale",
items: [17, 20, 10, 11] },
{ section_uid: "hammers",
items: [17, 26, 45, 40]}]

items: [
{ listing_id: 17,
uid: "item_17" },
{ listing_id: 26,
uid: "item_26"}]
```

Note that an Item may belong to two sections (in this example, item 17 is a hammer that is on sale). To display this data, I will grab each Section and all associated Items by their IDs in the "items" field of the sections JSON.

I have reviewed some of the documentation and [example of the many-to-many](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormlite-jdbc/trunk/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/manytomany/) relationship on ORMLite, but am unsure of which way I should proceed on a few questions...

1. If I want to do JOIN queries, I am forced to create SectionItems that contain references to Sections and Items and then query on those SectionItems for each section UID. Is this the proper way to go about things? It'd be nice to just have Sections and Items and query on all Items in Sections.items ordered by the order in the "items" array.
2. The order of item ids in the "items" section is important. Should my "JOIN intermediary" SectionItems keep track of the order of the item in the "items" array or if I insert the SectionItems in the same order as "items" will I be given that order back if I sort by date created/updated?
3. In the same vein as question 2, is there any reason not to attach the sectionUID to the "JOIN intermediary" class for faster querying or is it already doing that behind the scenes?
4. If sections are updated with new items or items are moved around in the "items" array and an update it required to the section, is it inefficient to delete all SectionItems that match that section and recreate the SectionItems for the new section?

Note, I will never have to grab an Item and ask which Section(s) it is a part of if that changes anything.

Many thanks in advance for help and guidance!